# What are some major applications of Identity based signatures (IBS) in real life?

Tags: signature

I read about Identity Based Signatures this week. I was thinking about its application in major fields like IoT etc. Are there any such applications?

For example: Multi-signature have application in cryptowallets. I am trying to see are there any major application of IBS like this.

Thanks.